# Visual Studio and namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I am attempting to move some code from one VS2008 project to another.

The project I am taking the code from works perfectly and I am not changing the code in any way when copying it to the new project.

The code is along the lines of :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace CommonTools
{

public class ColumnCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
     .....
}
}
```

The problem I have is that in the "new" project VS does not find "CollectionEditor" within the supplied namespaces and as such the project will not build.

Both the "new" and "old" projects are targeting .NET 3.5

Any ideas where I am going wrong here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have the

```
 System.Design.dll
```

assembly added to your refenerances?

you can see in which namespace and assembly it is at [CollectionEditor Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your new project references the same assemblies that your old project did.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) Says that `System.ComponentModel.Design.ColectionEditor` is in `System.Design.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using 'Go To Definition' on `CollectionEditor` in the original solution to see what you should have included?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have include this "System.Design.dll"?